# make rules with existing target, existing prerequisites but no recipe

Tags: c, makefile

I was looking at the net-snmp code and I found something odd in the Makefile of the snmplib itself. The last couple of thousands of lines are nothing but rules in this form:

```
./dir_utils.lo: ../include/net-snmp/output_api.h
```

for EVERY library object and header file. Even those that are not compiled, depending on which flags are selected in the configure script.

I looked at the "make" manual but I didn't find this exact case. It may be (as stated in 5.9) that they do this to exclude the possibility that an implicit recipe is called on the target, but other than that I have no idea.

Another reason might be to "break" the compilation if the library is tampered with (deleting whatever header in the project causes in fact the makefile to crash because it can't execute the rule).

This is an educated guess but I would like to know the theory behind this. I mean the makefile already builds whatever it has to build, why include all these rules in explicit form?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a `.c.lo` *suffix rule* in the Makefile? If so, then there doesn't need to be an explicit recipe for each of those targets.

Comment: Yes there is:

`.c.lo:`

  `$(LIBTOOL) --mode=compile $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<`

Answer (score 2):

As I expect you know, the `Makefile` is generated by the `./configure` script.
All the lines that interest you are auto-generated dependencies. Actually,
they are just the appended contents of the file `Makefile.depend` in the same
directory, which is part of the distribution and was generated with the aid 
of gcc ahead of time.

So e.g.

```
./dir_utils.lo: ../include/net-snmp/output_api.h
```

just informs `make` of the vitally important fact that `./dir_utils.lo`
depends on `../include/net-snmp/output_api.h`. Then if `./dir_utils.lo`
is older than `../include/net-snmp/output_api.h`, `make` will re-make
`./dir_utils.lo` provided it has some recipe to do that, which it has.

Here is a project:

**main.c**

```
#include "hw.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts(HW);
    return 0;
}
```

**hw.h**

```
#ifndef HW_H
#define HW_H
#define HW "Hello World"
#endif
```

**Makefile**

```
CC := gcc

.PHONY: all clean

all: hw

hw: main.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $<


clean:
    rm -f hw main.o
```

Build and run it:

```
$ make && ./hw
gcc    -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -o hw main.o
Hello World
```

But there's a bug in the makefile. It doesn't know that `main.o`
depends on `hw.h`:

```
$ touch hw.h
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Append that dependency to the makefile:

```
main.o: hw.h
```

and retry:

```
$ make
gcc    -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -o hw main.o
```

Bug fixed.

Comment: " if ./dir_utils.lo is older than ../include/net-snmp/output_api.h, make will re-make ./dir_utils.lo provided it has some recipe to do that, which it has." Thank you, this was exactly the answer I was looking for.